# NodeJS child process kill

Tags: node.js, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way of ensuring that a child process has been killed?

I currently have the following code:

```
let p = child_process.spawn(app, args);
...
try{
   p.kill('SIGKILL');
} catch(e) {
   console.error("Killing process exception:", e);
}

job = setInterval( () => {
  if(p.killed || timeout === true){
    clearInterval(job);
    callback();
  }
}, 100);
setTimeout( () => {
  console.log("Killing process timeout!");
  timeout = true;
}, 1000);
```

I check periodically (100 ms period) if the killing signal has been properly send to the process and, in that moment, I assume that the process has been killed; but, to ensure that the process is not locked, I set a timeout of 1 second.

Many times the timeout is fired, independently of waiting for 1 second or 10 seconds.

The code below is executed in linux; if working in WSL, then everything seems to work properly